# Remove one iteration from every instance of a pattern with a RegEx?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

Let's say I have the following text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur aaBaaBaaB adipiscing elit.
>
> aaBaaB
>
> aaB Ut in risus quis elit posuere faucibus sed vitae metus. aaBaaBaaBaaB
>
> Fusce nec tortor in dolor aaBaaBaaB porttitor viverra. aaB

I'm trying to figure out how to perform a regular expression search and replace on this in such a way that the output is:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur aaBaaB adipiscing elit.
>
> aaB
>
> Ut in risus quis elit posuere faucibus sed vitae metus. aaBaaBaaB
>
> Fusce nec tortor in dolor aaBaaB porttitor viverra.

That is, to remove one "`aaB`" from each pattern of it. Is this actually possible, and if so, how would it be done? Specifically, I intend to do this in Sublime Text 2 as a RegEx search/replace in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead:

```
(?=(?<w>[a-z]{2}[A-Z]{1})\s)\k<w>
```

You just need to make sure you have case-sensitive matching on.

example: http://regex101.com/r/sK8bG1

Answer (score 1):

Use either the leading or trailing whitespace to remove the first or last substring. Either of these work:

`(\s+)(aaB)` with `$1` in the Replace field

or

`(aaB)(\s+)` with `$2` in the Replace field